# MapBox: How to render object buried underground in 3d?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

When the camera is tilted very close to the ground, I want to make some ground parts transparent to show a buried object like a pipe.

libraries I am using: Mapbox Gl Js, Three.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [outline effect](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outline#webgl_postprocessing_outline)?  It looks it could be what you need.

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far.